# How to get this context of a button in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jstl

I want to create a function for specific actions in order to submit buttons in my web forms. I have the function:

```
$(".buttonsClass").on('click', function () { submitButton( this ); }

function submitButton( button )
{
        $(button).closest('form').find('#action').val( button.id );
        $(button).closest('form').submit();
}
```

But, when the user is using a text input related to a button like a text to search, I need to submit the form clicking the button "Search" when the user press enter, how to pass the button as `this` and not as the button? Look the code:

```
$('.textToSearch').on('keypress', function() {
   if (enter) 
      submitButton( $('form .buttonToSubmit') );
});
```

As you can see the button parameter in the `submitButton` function will not as `this` context, because will index something like this:

```
$($('form.buttonToSubmit'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger button click on enter hit. As shown below:

```
 $(".buttonsClass").trigger('click');
```

This will execute the same button click on key press enter.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try detecting thr ke pressed via the event and trigger the submit like so:

```
$('.textToSearch').on('keypress', function(e) {   
   var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
   if(keycode == 13) {
       $('#formId').trigger('submit');
   }
});
```